# Show loading template in Ember

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

I have been doing a lot of tinkering with this and can't seem to get it working. I am looking to show my loading template while waiting for my model promise to return.

My understanding is, by default, if I have `app/templates/loading.hbs`, this template will be rendered across all routes. However, even with that template in place whenever I switch between routes the old route remains displayed until the model returns, at which point my liquid fire transition occurs and you're taken to the next route.

I have tried various version of creating nested loading templates for each route, tried creating subroutes for each route for the loading template, and have even messed with the beforeModel/afterModel methods that are available but I am making no progress. This is the last hurdle I want to cross before launching and am perplexed as to why I can't get it working.  Here is a bunch of my code I feel is relevant.

Note: I am using Ember CLI and Liquid Fire. My data is also being returned to the model from am Ember Service for the time being.

**Router**

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('reviews', function() {
    this.route('index', {path: '/'});
    this.route('review', {path: '/:review_id'});
  });
  this.route('movies');
  this.route('about');
});
```

**app/template/loading.hbs**

```
<div class="content-container">
    <h1>Ish be loading</h1>
</div>
```

**Slowest Model Route**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    activate() {
        this._super();
        $("html,body").animate({scrollTop:0},"fast");
        $("body").addClass('movies');
    },
    deactivate() {
        $("body").removeClass('movies');
    },
    model() {
        const movies = this.get('movies');
        return movies.getMoviesInAlphOrder();
    },
    afterModel: function() {
        $(document).attr('title', 'Slasher Obscura - Movie Database');
    },
    movies: Ember.inject.service()
});
```

**app.js**

```
App = Ember.Application.extend({
    modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
    podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
    Resolver,
    ...
});
loadInitializers(App, config.modulePrefix);
```

I have read the docs on Ember's site along with various other Google resources and can't seem to figure out why my loading template isn't rendering at all. Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect that if your route handler's model hook doesn't return a promise, I doubt Ember ever has a chance to show a loading template. Also, you listed `app/template/loading.hbs` (should be templates), but maybe that's just a typo? What have you tried already to test the functionality is working correctly?

Comment: I believe this answer was answered in another thread now. It's not my model that is taking a while to return, which would cause the loading screen to show, but it is the rendering of the model that is slow. I need to chunk out my data to speed that process up.